# initializing jpa entitymanagerfactory in applicationscope bean in jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2, persistence, jpa-2.0, managed-bean, servletcontextlistener

This is my first post on stackoverflow

I want to create EntityManagerFactory in the ApplicationScope bean in jsf 2. 
Here is my bean

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean(eager = true)

public class ApplicationContext implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
private EntityManager entityManager = null;

public ApplicationContext(){

}

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@PostConstruct
public void applicationInitialized(){
    System.out.println("application is being initialized");
    this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonalProject");
    this.entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@PreDestroy
public void applicationDestroyed(){
    System.out.println("application being destroyed");

}

}
```

I get a huge exception stacktrace for this.

```
  com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean applicationContext
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader
  context: /PersonalProject
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6d4c1103

Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PersonalProject] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:65)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    at com.justme.web.gui.ApplicationContext.applicationInitialized(ApplicationContext.java:49)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PersonalProject] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:127)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PersonalProject] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:210)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidTypeForSerializedAttribute(ValidationException.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.converters.SerializedMetadata.process(SerializedMetadata.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processSerialized(MappingAccessor.java:1641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processJPAConverters(MappingAccessor.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1495)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1365)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:968)
    ... 28 more
Mar 17, 2013 11:40:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean applicationContext
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean applicationContext
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:255)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader
  context: /PersonalProject
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6d4c1103

Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PersonalProject] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:65)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    at com.justme.web.gui.ApplicationContext.applicationInitialized(ApplicationContext.java:49)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PersonalProject] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:127)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PersonalProject] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:210)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidTypeForSerializedAttribute(ValidationException.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.converters.SerializedMetadata.process(SerializedMetadata.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processSerialized(MappingAccessor.java:1641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processJPAConverters(MappingAccessor.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1495)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1365)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:968)
    ... 28 more
```

the root cause says that it is because the class Post does not implement serializable.
but it already implements it as follows.

```
public class Post implements Serializable {}
```

I am getting this problem only in ApplicationScoped ManagedBean.
If I try to create EntityManagerFactory using a ServletContextListener then it is created just fine.

what can be the problem? 
Am I missing some knowledge about the ApplicationScoped bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if class Post had a field named content of type Object:

```
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [content] on the entity class [class com.justme.model.entities.Post] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
```

JPA does not know how to convert Object to a column type in a database.

One more thing. Your are using EntityManager as a field in ApplicationContext. EntityManager class is not thread-save, so using it in a application-scoped class would casus a lot of problems.

You had better remove EntityManager field, remove setEntityManager method and rewrite getEntityManager

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();
}
```

EntityManagerFactory is thread save.